# internet connection stopped working, but wifi connection looks fine (ubuntu 18.04.2)

Tags: wireless, internet, router

I see many other posts with the same issue but cannot find any solution nor explanation and keep clicking on links endlessly so I would appreciate some guidance on this issue, rather than "just trying" to "Forget the connection" and setting it up again.

What I have tried:

Connection to my home wifi seems fine: `Settings > Wifi` shows my wifi and the signal strength is "good", an IPv4 Address of 192.168.0.4, and other normal-looking information.

Typing `192.168.0.4` into my browser opens the "Apache2 Ubuntu Default Page".

Typing `192.168.0.1` into my browser opens up a page with my router configuration.

Result of `dig 1.1.1.1`:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.11.3-1ubuntu1.8-Ubuntu <<>> 1.1.1.1  
;; global connections: +cmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

Result of `ip route`

```
default via 192.168.0.1 dev wlp3s0 proto dhcp metric 600
169.254.0.0/16 dev wlp3s0 scope link metric 1000
192.168.0.0/24 dev wlp3s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.4 metric 600
```

Result of `ping 8.8.8.8`:

```
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
ping: sendmsg: Operation not permitted
```

Result of `ping example.com`:

```
ping: example.com: Name or service not known
```

Running `nmcli dev show wlp3s0` spits a bunch of things, but I don't know what to look for.

I did reboot my computer, with no change.

*Note.*  I *do* have the `ip` command on my system (which should be enough for diagnostics), but I do *not* have any of the following commands that I see in other answers: `ifconfig`, `netstats`, `route`, `arp`, `traceroute` (which all seem deprecated?).

Comment: The problem is external to your network. Is this in a corporate environment, or home environment? Cable or DSL modem, or something else? Have you **POWER CYCLED** the router/modem?

Comment: This is my home wifi.  There were some weird issues with it, and I power cycled it.  I am able to use wifi with several other devices, just not my ubuntu machine.  I can try power cycling again, just to see, and forgetting the connection on the computer and setting it up again, but I would prefer tracing the issue as far as I can first.

Comment: Describe your network configuration. I assume that you have a wireless router (what brand?) connected to a cable/DSL modem? Did you power cycle the modem, and any switches/hubs in your network path? Describe the "weird issues" you were having. It might help me. Are you using Access Control lists in your router?

Comment: Maybe your ISP is down? That's why you can not ping the outside world.

Comment: @heynnema I tried power cycling (that is, I switched off the router and, this time, waited several minutes before turning it back on, rather than switching off and immediately on again), and now internet works on my ubuntu machine.  Prior to that, I also had my computer "forget connection", but it had made non difference.  Just for completeness, I shouldn't have spoken of "weird issues", it's just that internet stopped working in the house, but at different times for different devices (as far as I could tell, but this is more anecdotal than scientific).

Comment: @Karlom The problem couldn't have been the ISP as I was able to use the internet on all other devices (laptop, tablets, phones). In conclusion: try **POWER CYCLING**.  Feels a bit brute forcish...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments...

Since you get a proper IP address of 192.168.0.4, and you **can** get to the routers admin page at 192.168.0.1, but you can't ping 8.8.8.8, the problem must be with your router, or your cable/DSL modem. It **is** a little strange that you can get to the Internet with some other computers.

You've already rebooted the computer. **POWER CYCLE** your router **AND** cable/DSL modem. Wait 15 seconds between powering back on. Power on the modem first, wait 15 seconds, then power on the router.

Retry Internet access.